# set a parameters in a jsp page with tiles

Tags: parameters, jstl, jsp-tags, tiles

what i have is :

```
<definition name="error" extends="baseLayout">
<..../>
<put-attribute name="login" value="login.jsp"/>
</definition>
```

in login.jsp a have a variable ;

```
<body onload='<c:if test="${not empty param.login_erro}">Username don't match </c:if>
...</body>
```

i call this tiles when i have error in login by a controller /error.htm
how to set the variable login_error to 1 to display the message (error login)
thank'w

Answer (score 0):

Any `EL` that is looking at `${param.something}` can only find the `parameter` if it was on the original request.

In your case, your `controller` would need to add an `attribute` to the request like:

```
if( userLoginFailed ) {
  request.setAttribute("login_erro", "1");
}
```

...then your jsp would check for `${not empty login_erro}`.

`${foo}` will find an `attribute` named **foo**

`${param.foo}` will find a `parameter` named **foo**

`${foo.bar}` will find an `attribute` named **foo** and call its `.getBar()` method